# Cambiar progresivamente la opacidad de divs mediante CSS

Tags: css, css3

Busco una solución puramente CSS al siguiente problema.

Tengo un div que contiene un número indeterminado de divs,
busco que dado un color RGB, por ejemplo, `(0,0,0)` y un range de valores de opacidad `(0.3 - 0.7)` vaya variando la opacidad de los divs en ese rango de manera progresiva.

De momento tengo lo siguiente. Usando los selectores `first-child` y `last-child` :

```css
.container {
  background : #f7f7f7;
  padding : 10px;
}

.container div {
  height : 30px;
  margin : 5px;
  background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.container div:first-child {
  background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.container div:last-child {
  background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
</div>
```

¿Es posible utilizando solamente CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS funciona con selectores, es imposible hacer calculos o iteraciones, lo mas cercano seria utilizar 'nth-child' para referenciar a un child de un elemento.

```
.container div:nth-child(1) { background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); };
.container div:nth-child(2) { background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); };
.container div:nth-child(3) { background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); };
```

Pero de esta manera debes especificar estaticamente el valor de opacidad, no de manera aleatoria, si los child del elemento container contiene mas hijos a su vez, estos se van a ver afectados, para solamente se aplique a los hijos inmediatamente inferiores entonces

```
.container > div:nth-child(1) { background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); };
.container > div:nth-child(2) { background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); };
.container > div:nth-child(3) { background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); };
```

para obtener lo que quieres necesariamente debes utilizar Javascript para dar un valor aleatorio a la opacidad y adicionalmente para utilizar un bucle donde asignes la opacidad a 'n' cantidad de hijos.

Con SASS o LESS puedes utilizar iteradores pero a la final esto genera CSS así que estas restringido a la cantidad de iteraciones que especifiques en el preprocesador así que llegaras a lo mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Con un número determinado se puede hacer, exediendo el número el color se mantiene. un ejemplo claro es un breadcrumb:

```
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(207,24%,35%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(207,24%,35%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(207,24%,40%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(207,24%,40%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(207,24%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(207,24%,45%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(207,24%,50%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(207,24%,50%,1); }
    .breadcrumb li:last-child a {
      background: hsla(207,24%,80%,1) !important;
      color: black;
      pointer-events: none;
      cursor: default;
    }
```

La clave esta en especular la cantidad de elemento que vamos a usar, en tu ejemplo podriamos insertar este codigo:

```
.container div:nth-child(2) { background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); }
.container div:nth-child(3) { background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); }
.container div:nth-child(4) { background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando la directiva [`@for`](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#for) en [Sass](http://thesassway.com/) puedes conseguirlo mediante `CSS` (preprocesado):

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {  

  div:nth-child(#{$i})  {

    opacity: calc(.2 * #{$i});
  } 
}
```

**[Ver ejemplo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWLqwg)**

Comment: Genial saber esto! La única pega que el ejemplo no funciona, lo he arreglado usando `opacity: #{$i * 0.2};` Muchas gracias!